# Do I need to disallow mediapartners-google in robots.txt for SEO?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, googlebot, robots.txt

I found that most of the websites disallow `mediapartners-google` in *robots.txt*.

Why do I need to do block `mediapartners-google`? Can blocking it help withp better SEO or does it not matter for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all in SEO, because it's [AdSense crawler](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/99376?hl=en)

If you've AdSense Ads in your site, then you shouldn't block `mediapartners-google` user agent in robots.txt. But if you don't serve Adsense ads in your site, then you can surely block it just like other webmaster do it. If you see such a user-agent in your website log and if you think it consume more bandwidth then you're free to block it. But they have already configured their bot very well and crawl required and important pages only.